# Chrome extension Secure Shell socket access

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to make an SSH-based extension for Chrome, but I can't figure out how the secure shell extension is able to access raw sockets in Chrome.

It only has these permissions:
[image]

Yet I'm able to connect on port 22 via SSH.  I know it uses PNaCl through Enscripten, but how do these provide raw socket access?
Has Google hard-coded whitelabel permission to the sockets API just for this extension?

Comment: Chromium source code whitelists like 100 hardcoded extension IDs mostly by Google to grant them access to private API. You can try whitelisting locally via `--whitelisted-extension-id=.......` [switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you check the manifest, you will see that it has this permission "terminalPrivate".

Then if you poke alittle bit around you will find those posts:

http://chromium.2324630.n4.nabble.com/crx-Use-chrome-terminalPrivate-API-in-chromeOS-extension-app-td17265.html

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-hterm/PtR2q2p_vss

The "good" comments you find on those sites are:

> chrome.terminalPrivate exists, but it's native code only available to
>   the Secure Shell chrome extension, and only on Chrome OS.

Or this one:

> chrome.xPrivate APIs are, well, private APIs that are only used by
>   certain Chrome or Google extensions and applications.

Comment: this is incorrect ... `terminalPrivate` has nothing to do with raw sockets.  that is only for the [`crosh`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform2/+/master/crosh/) tool.

Answer (score 1):

Secure Shell gets access to raw sockets via (P)NaCl because it has been whitelisted in the Chromium source.  ugly, i know.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/master/nassh/doc/hack.md#Whitelisted-Permissions

if you want to do raw sockets in your own Chrome app, you can do so via JavaScript:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket

if you want to access raw sockets from Chrome extensions, or via a [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/), then currently you won't be able to do so.  those only have access to [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) currently (which is basically HTTP).  this is why projects like [WebSockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify) exist.

Comment: Is there any reason in particular that the secure shell app does not use the standard chrome.sockets permission?

Comment: chrome.sockets are only available to apps, not extensions, and would be a performance hit relative to direct NaCl access.  every packet would have to be received by the JS side then sent over the PPAPI layers to the NaCl side to process.

Comment: But the secure shell (pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo) is an app, not an extension, no? I just looked at the manifest and it definitely looks like an app to me. It could just as well ask for chrome.sockets. I thought those permissions were then passed down into the NaCL module, too (for example, if you wanted to use webports/sdl-net) ?

Comment: it isn't an extension or an app.  it's a "1.5v" app which was an experimental version before the current "v2" apps we have today.  the "1.5v" has been deprecated for a long time, but Secure Shell never migrated off for various reasons.  it means in some ways it behaves like an extension (e.g. sharing the cookie jar), but in other ways it behaves like an app (e.g. it shows up in the app list).